# Update on table error with db2 CLI/ODBC Connection from C Application?

Tags: c, db2, db2-luw

Getting error while updating a remote database from C application connected through DB2 CLI/ODBC Driver.

The error occurs with the function SQLExecute of the UPDATE-statement (returns -1).

SQLSTATE: 42828, Native Error Code: 4294966786, [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0510N  UPDATE or DELETE is not allowed against the specified cursor.  SQLSTATE=42828

Thanks,
Mohammad Shamshad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programming error. More information at the link below.
db2 "? [SQL0510N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic2.html#sql0510n)"

> **SQL0510N**  UPDATE or DELETE is not allowed against the specified
>   cursor.
>
> **Explanation**:
>
> The program attempted to execute an UPDATE or DELETE WHERE CURRENT OF
>   cursor statement against a table or view definition that does not
>   permit the requested update or delete operation. For example, this
>   error can occur in a delete from a read-only view or in an update
>   where the cursor was not defined with the FOR UPDATE clause.

From the log file provided:

> SQLPrepare(65537,SELECT * FROM SPAUTH WHERE TRMCAU=? AND PRFCAU=? AND
>   LVL2AU=?  ORDER BY TRMCAU ASC,  PRFCAU ASC,  LVL2AU ASC   OPTIMIZE FOR
>   40 ROWS,SQL_NTS);
>   SQLSetCursorName(65537, SPAUTHU);
>   ...
>   SQLPrepare(65539,UPDATE SPAUTH set TRMCAU=?,PRFCAU=?,LVL2AU=?,AUTHAU=?
>   where current of SPAUTHU, SQL_NTS);
>   SQLExecute(65539);
>
> [ERROR] 0315-152416 Process 31244 File isp406000o/qcsrc/TestUpd1.c
>   Line 1653 :    SQLSTATE: 42828, Native Error Code: 4294966786,
>   [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/AIX64] SQL0510N  UPDATE or DELETE is not allowed
>   against the specified cursor.  SQLSTATE=42828

Cursor SPAUTHU is not updatable, but you try to issue a positioned update against it.
[DECLARE CURSOR statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000937.html):

> A column in the select list of the outer fullselect associated with a
>   cursor is **updatable** if each of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The cursor is deletable
>     ...
>
> A cursor is deletable if each of the following conditions is true:
>   ...
>
> - The outer fullselect does not include an ORDER BY clause (even if
>     the ORDER BY clause is nested in a view), and the FOR UPDATE clause
>     has not been specified
>
> ...

Add `FOR UPDATE` clause at the end of your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Table has full permissions to update and delete.But still getting error.. No view defined for this table.

Comment: Is it necessary to bind db2cli.lst to unblock the update from cursor ar Client location(where CLI Driver Installed)
strcpy (bindFileName, "//@db2cli.lst");
rc = SQLCreatePkg(hdbc,
                                                                                                                                                bindFileName,
strlen(bindFileName),
"GRANT='x';BLOCKING=no;",-3, // SQL_NTS);

Comment: Show your C code and point to the line where you get the error.

Comment: Hi Mark,

Please find below link for my C Source file and Debug report

C Source:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=124N_MBUwlsJBaBc2tpyVI3gnRmgGl6gp

Debug Report:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=13OeuZXpMqtYGYq0bq85YfERFaDo4IZL9


Thanks,
Shamshad

Comment: @MOHAMMADSHAMSHADHUSSAIN I've updated the answer after your files analysis.

Comment: Thanks it worked with FOR UPDATE clause...Now able to update the data on Remote database.